# Generalized eigenvalue problem and standard eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following generalized eigenvalue problem from classical mechanics

$$\omega^2 Tv = Uv$$

where $T$ is a real, positive definite matrix and $U$ is positive semidefinite. To find the eigenvalues, I have to calculate

$$\det(-\omega^2 T + U) = 0$$

Why can't I simply write $T^{-1}Uv = \omega^2 v$ and solve it as a standard eigenvalue problem?

Can you suggest me any resources (books, etc) about this topic?

Comment: You can. If one matrix is non singular, then the generalized eigenvalue problem reduces to the simple one.

Comment: There is a strong link with the Rayleigh quotient $X^TTX/X^TUX$. Here are two references http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/2010/chapter12.pdf. and  http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/courses/ece271B-F09/handouts/Dimensionality3.pdf.