# Rewrite generalized eigenvalue problem as standard eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

I have two matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and I want to find the values of $\lambda$ such that

$$
\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \lambda \cdot \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{v}
$$

- $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are positive definite and symmetric

Then I want to rewrite it as a standard eigenvalue problem. It means, find $\textbf{C}$ such that

$$
\mathbf{C} \cdot \mathbf{u} = \lambda \cdot \textbf{u}
$$

for some $\mathbf{R}$ such $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{R}\cdot \mathbf{u}$

This [math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709630/generalized-eigenvalue-problem-and-standard-eigenvalue-problem) shows that we could have

$$
\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{B^{-1}} \cdot \mathbf{A} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mathbf{R} = \mathbf{I}
$$

This matrix $\mathbf{C}$ is not necessarily symmetric and I want $\mathbf{C}$ to have the same properties (symmetric, positive definite).

**Question:** How can I find $\mathbf{C}$ symmetric and positive definite matrix ?

Comment: Assuming, in general, that $A$, $B$ and $\lambda$ are not singular, the equation $$ \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \lambda \cdot \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{v} $$ is equivalent to $$ \mathbf{B}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \lambda \cdot \mathbf{v} $$ So you cannot create a symmetric positive definite $\mathbf C$ out of nowhere. If $\mathbf C$ exists, then it needs to be equal to $\mathbf{B}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{A}$.

Not every eigenvalue problem involves a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompose $B$ like

$$
B = P \cdot \left[b\right] \cdot P^{T}
$$

With $\left[b\right]$ a diagonal matrix and $P$ a orthonormal matrix:

$$
P \cdot P^{T} = I
$$

In that way we rewrite

$$
A v = \lambda B v
$$
$$
A v = \lambda P\left[b\right]P^{T} v
$$
$$
A \underbrace{P\cdot P^{T}}_{I} v = \lambda P\left[b\right]P^{T} v
$$
$$
P^{T} AP \cdot P^{T}v = \lambda \left[b\right] \cdot P^{T} v
$$
$$
P^{T} AP \underbrace{\left[\sqrt{b}\right]^{-1} \cdot \left[\sqrt{b}\right]}_{I} P^{T}v = \lambda \left[\sqrt{b}\right] \cdot \left[\sqrt{b}\right] P^{T} v
$$
$$
\underbrace{\left[\sqrt{b}\right]^{-1} P^{T} AP \left[\sqrt{b}\right]^{-1} }_{C} \cdot \underbrace{\left[\sqrt{b}\right] P^{T}v}_{u} = \lambda  \cdot \underbrace{ \left[\sqrt{b}\right] P^{T} v}_{u}
$$

Then

$$
C = \left[\sqrt{b}^{-1}\right] P^{T} AP \left[\sqrt{b}^{-1}\right]
$$
$$
R = \left[\sqrt{b}\right] P^{T}
$$